# Save Feasible Solutions SCIP - Python - OR Tools

Tags: scipy, or-tools, scipy-optimize, scip

I am new using SCIP with OR Tools and Python to solve a MIP problem with exact solution, for this reason I have two questions:

1. How can I get the feasible solutions for each of the iterations in the branch-and-bound? I would like to save the local optimum, highlighted with (*) in the graph:

[Output Branch-and-Bound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKxBR.png)

2. How can I stop this branch-and-bound algorithm by “% gap” or “time”?

Comment: 1) This has nothing to do with scipy. 2) Calling them local optima sounds inaccurate. 3) For 1 -> You would need to define a callback (or [eventhandler](https://www.scipopt.org/doc/html/EVENT.php)), not sure about or-tools supporting this. 4) For 2 -> You would set solver-options, not sure how to pass them through or-tools. I recommend reading SCIP docs for recognition of the relevant param and or-tools docs to learn about param-passing.